Trouble integrating Flutterwave Library with node js App on localhost
I am getting a TypeError of  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create') when i try to run my code, i am getting this error from the Initialize payment line, the const response = await flutterwave.Payment.create(payload)
const paymentFlutterwave = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { appointmentId } = req.body;

    const appointmentData = await appointmentModel.findById(appointmentId);

    if (!appointmentData || appointmentData.cancelled) {
      return res.json({
        success: false,
        message: "Appointment Cancelled or not found",
      });
    }

    // Payload for Flutterwave payment
    const payload = {
      tx_ref: `tx_${appointmentId}_${Date.now()}`, 
      amount: appointmentData.amount,
      currency: process.env.CURRENCY || "NGN", 
      redirect_url: process.env.REDIRECT_URL, 
      payment_options: "card, banktransfer",
      customer: {
        email: "testing@gmail.com",
        phonenumber: "750678786898",
        name: "test customer",
      },
      customizations: {
        title: "Appointment Payment",
        description: `Payment for appointment ID ${appointmentId}`,
        logo: "https://your-logo-url.com/logo.png",
      },
    };

    // Initialize payment
    const response = await flutterwave.Payment.create(payload);

    if (response.status === "success") {
      res.json({ success: true, data: response });
    } else {
      res.json({ success: false, message: response.message });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.json({ success: false, message: error.message });
  }
};

const paymentCallback = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const transactionId = req.query.transaction_id;
  
      if (!transactionId) {
        return res.status(400).send("Transaction ID is required.");
      }
  
      const response = await flutterwave.Transaction.verify({ id: transactionId });
  
      if (response.status === "success" && response.data.status === "successful") {
        const appointmentId = response.data.tx_ref.split('_')[1];
        await appointmentModel.findByIdAndUpdate(appointmentId, { paid: true });
        res.status(200).send("Payment verified successfully!");
      } else {
        res.status(400).send("Payment verification failed.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error verifying payment:", error);
      res.status(500).send("An error occurred during payment verification.");
    }
  };

i tried to apply flutterwave to my backend and its not working


Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')

This error means that the object flutterwave.Payment that you're trying to reference here doesn't exist.
    const response = await flutterwave.Payment.create(payload);

What documentation are you using for Flutterwave? I'm not familiar with that product, but when I look at the "Usage" documentation for the Node.js SDK, I don't see anything called Payment.
Looking at your payload, it looks like you might be trying to get a payment link. From their documentation, it says you need to make an HTTP call to do that.
  const response = await axios.post(
    'https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/payments',
    payload,
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.FLW_SECRET_KEY}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }
  );



Thank you very much, this solved my issue... i am still a bit new at coding and I am not familiar on how to read documentation yet... but the setup is working now
